# BusyBox (initramfs) after forced shutdown

Tags: boot, grub2, initramfs, busybox

I have found a lot of questions with problems similar to mine but none of the solutions have worked for me so far. I'll try to describe everything I've tried so this might be long.

Today I was working on my computer as usual (Ubuntu 22.04) and it went into suspension mode because I stopped using it for a bit. When I moved the mouse to restart it it didn't work. I tried pressing a couple of keys on the keyboard and it didn't work either. Out of habit from working with windows I pressed ctrl+alt+sup. The screen was still blank with a _ on the top left corner. I decided to force shutdown. After that every time Ubuntu started booting it got stuck in the same blank screen with the _ (it didn't blink).

Other people with a similar problem were able to open a terminal by pressing ctrl+alt+F1 or F2 or other F. This didn't work for me, I wasn't able to open any terminal.

Next I tried to boot recovery mode via grub menu. This showed a new problem this time with the keyboard, every time I pressed a key it either didn't work or took the command twice, which made navigating the grub menu impossible. To fix this I went to the bios and enabled CSM.

After enabling CSM if I boot ubuntu I get to a screen that says:

```
gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
-Check rootdelay= (did the systemwait long enough?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=xxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

and prompts a BusyBox shell that says (initramfs). Running the recovery mode takes me to this same screen as well.

Some people with a similar issue fixed it by changing the SATA operations in the BIOS from RAID to AHCI, but mine is already in AHCI.

Also I tried recovering the data from the hard drives by booting ubuntu from a flashdrive but the drives are not being recognized, I have 2 4TB hard drives and gparted says I only have 8GB of memory. Also the whole screen has a pink tint to it.

This all sounds very familiar from when I first bought the computer and tried to install Ubuntu. I had the same issues with the hard drives not being recognized. Apparently there was a conflict with the VGA connector which was solved by switching it off in the motherboard. I checked and the switch is still off, so I'm out of ideas.

I'd appreciate any help, if not for fixing the issue, for recovering the data in the hard drives.

**Edit to add required info:**

**PC specs:**

(CPU): Procesador de 24 núcleos AMD Ryzen Threadripper PRO 5965WX (4.5GHz, CACHE de 140MB)

Motherboard: ASUS® Pro WS WRX80E-SAGE SE WIFI (Intel dual 10 G LAN, USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 puerto Tipo-C, SLI)

(RAM): 256 GB Kingston DDR4 3200 MHz ECC Registrada (8 x 32 GB)

Graphics: 4 GB PNY NVIDIA T400 - GDDR6, 384 Núcleos CUDA - 3 x mDP

1ª Unidad M.2 SSD: 1 TB CORSAIR FORCE MP600 NVMe PCIe M.2 SSD (hasta 4950 MB/R, 4000 MB/W)

1st hard drive: 4 TB SEAGATE BARRACUDA SATA-III 3,5", 6 GB/s, 5400 RPM, 256 MB CACHÉ

2nd hard drive: 4 TB SEAGATE BARRACUDA SATA-III 3,5", 6 GB/s, 5400 RPM, 256 MB CACHÉ

**requested commands**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c349 Logitech, Inc. LogiG MKeyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler 100 G3/G4/SE9 G2/50
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c063 Logitech, Inc. DELL Laser Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Milan IOMMU (rev 01)
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:05.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Milan Data Fabric; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Milan Data Fabric; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Milan Data Fabric; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Milan Data Fabric; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Milan Data Fabric; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Milan Data Fabric; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Milan Data Fabric; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Milan Data Fabric; Function 7
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117GL [T400 4GB] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
03:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship USB 3.0 Host Controller
20:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex
20:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Milan IOMMU (rev 01)
20:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
20:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
20:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
20:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
20:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
20:05.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
20:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
20:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
20:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
20:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
21:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Switch Upstream
22:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
22:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
22:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
22:03.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
22:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
22:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
22:08.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
22:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
23:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation E16 PCIe4 NVMe Controller (rev 01)
24:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM3242 USB 3.2 Host Controller
25:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10G X550T (rev 01)
25:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10G X550T (rev 01)
26:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
27:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
28:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
29:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
29:00.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
29:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
2a:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
2b:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
2c:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
2c:00.1 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP
2c:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship USB 3.0 Host Controller
2c:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
40:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex
40:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Milan IOMMU (rev 01)
40:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
40:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
40:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
40:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
40:05.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
40:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
40:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
40:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
40:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
41:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
42:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
60:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex
60:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Milan IOMMU (rev 01)
60:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
60:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
60:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
60:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
60:05.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
60:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
60:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
60:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
60:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
61:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
62:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/scsi/scsi
Attached devices:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: Kingston Model: DataTraveler 3.0 Rev: PMAP
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 06
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the manufacturer and model of your PC and hard drives. Copy&paste the output of `dmesg` (or if necessary `sudo dmesg`), `cat /proc/scsi/scsi`, `lspci` and `lsusb` from the flashdrive live system.

Comment: I've never used those commands and the outputs from some of them are hundreds of lines long, should I copy everything or do I have to focus on something?

Comment: I guess especially the `dmesg` output is long. Look for information related to your hard drives or SATA controllers. I expect `cat /proc/scsi/scsi` not to produce much output, and this should be related to harddrives and CD/DVD drives.

Comment: I didn't find any lines related to SATA controllers in the dmesg output

Comment: `lspci` shows 3 SATA controller lines: `27:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)` `28:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia ...` `2a:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)` Searching for `ASM1062` leads to problem reports related to this controller. Unfortunately I cannot help further with this. The mainboaard seems to have 4 SATA ports on the AMD controller and 4 ports on the ASMedia controller(s). You could try to connect the harddrives to different SATA ports.

Comment: okey thanks for the lead. I tried changing ports and the problem is still there, but defenitely is a problem with the hard drives not being recognised.

Comment: To recover the data in the hard drives you yould try to connect them to a different computer, maybe booting a Live Linux. If this computer doesn't have SATA ports you could use a USB-SATA adapter.